# In an organizational appveyor account, how do I access repos from my organization, without letting the other members access my personal repos?

Tags: continuous-integration, appveyor

I created a new projet in an organizational appveyor account. The repository is an organizational github repo.

We are multiple co-admin in the organizational appveyor account, and their credentials are linked to the organizational account.

The problem is that if another co-admin connects to appveyor and tries to create a new project, my own personal repos are going to be displayed in the list. (i.e. the repos attached to my github token)

If I revoke my github token, then the project that were already created will fail on build because appveyor will not be able to checkout the sources.

Is there a way to access public repositories from an organizational account without attaching a personal github token ?

Answer (score 1):

A usual approach many big organizations follow is to have more granular control over what can be accessed by AppVeyor is creating a new GitHub user (optionally giving it access to only specific repos) and authorizing this user in AppVeyor (at https://ci.appveyor.com/account).

Unfortunately there are some costs involved as GitHub charges per user, but creating this kind of a “build bot” user is the best approach for now.